# how to return a managed class from a c++/cli static function

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I am trying to call unmanaged functions from a c# using c++/cli code.

I have code similar to this:

```
MyFileWrapper MyFileWrapper::ReadMyFile(System::String ^fileName)
{
    auto nativeMyFile=MyFile::ReadMyFile((char *) 
           System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(
           fileName).ToPointer());
    MyFileWrapper myFileWrapper=gcnew MyFileWrapper();
     // code will be added to read information from native object and convert them to wrapper properties. 
    return myFileWrapper;

}
```

But I am getting error that

```
 Error  2   error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'MyFileWrapper' to 'MyFileWrapper'  MyFileWrapper.cpp   
 Error  1   error C3673: 'MyFileWrapper' : class does not have a copy-constructor   MyFileWrapper.cpp
```

For the first error, the intelisense give me the following error which has better explanation:

```
    IntelliSense: no suitable user-defined conversion from "MyFileWrapper ^" to "MyFileWrapper" exists
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Learning when to use the hat^ is essential in C++/CLI programming.  Be sure to read a book or follow a good tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gcnew MyFileWrapper()` returns a `MyFileWrapper^` (i.e., a managed reference to a `MyFileWrapper` instance), not a `MyFileWrapper`.

```
MyFileWrapper^ MyFileWrapper::ReadMyFile(System::String^ fileName)
{
    ...
    MyFileWrapper^ myFileWrapper = gcnew MyFileWrapper();
    ...
    return myFileWrapper;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your return type and temporary variable should be `MyFileWrapper^`, after all they are managed.

Answer (score 0):

All the managed types in C++/CLI layer should be defined in the form of **TypeName ^**